Docusign e-signature API disabling reassigning not working
I am using the Docusign ruby SDK for e-signature API and want to disable reassigning to another email when creating Docusign envelope. To do this, I have specifically set allowReassign as false in the EnvelopeDefinition when creating the envelope.
Here is the code used to create the envelope:
      envelope_definition = DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition.new(emailSubject: email_subject, emailBlurb: email_blurb, status: "created", allowReassign: false)

      envelope_definition.documents = ...
      envelope_definition.recipients = ...
      envelope_definition.event_notification = ...
      envelope_summary = @envelopes_api.create_envelope(docusign_account_id, envelope_definition)

Here is the EnvelopeDefinition object:
#<DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopeDefinition:0x000000016fbd8128
@allow_reassign=false,
@email_blurb="<p dir=\"auto\">email body</p>",
@email_subject="email subject",
@status="created">

Here is the response from get_envelope API after creating the envelope which confirms that the allow_reassign flag is set to False:
<DocuSign_eSign::Envelope:0x0000000116bb0988
 @allow_comments="true",
 @allow_markup="false",
 @allow_reassign="false",
 @allow_view_history="true" 
.....

Allow reassign option still being shown when signing envelope
However, the option is still there as shown in the link to image above. I seem to remember the option actually not being there when Docusign was using the old UI so I'm not sure if this was missed when moving to the new UI.
I would really appreciate any help on this!

Go to https://apps-d.docusign.com/admin/signing-settings and login with the same user you used for your integration.
Under Signing Settings, there's a Delegation section with a single option.
You'll see this option checked, uncheck it:


Hey Inbar, thanks for the response!
Unfortunately, I am creating a Docusign integration for a multi-tenanted application. Does this mean that I need to programatically disable delegation for all tenants(customers) at the Docusign account level? Is this possible?
Also I am wondering why disabling delegation on an envelope level is not being used
